# After doing GridSearch why am I getting less accurate results?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

So I have applied random search first then grid search for my MLP Regressor. The thing is my R^2 for the optimum parameters suggested by randomsearch (hidden layers 18,18,18 (R^2= 0.90)) is better than the same suggested by gridsearch (hidden layers 17,17,17 (R^2= 0.89), why is that?

```
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPRegressor
from sklearn.model_selection import RandomizedSearchCV


mlp = MLPRegressor(random_state=42)
param_grid_random = {'hidden_layer_sizes': [(18,), (18,18,), (18,18,18,)],
              'activation': ['tanh','relu','logistic'],
              'solver': ['sgd', 'adam'],
              'learning_rate': ['constant','adaptive','invscaling'],
              'alpha': [0.0001, 0.05],
              'max_iter': [10000000000],
              'early_stopping': [False],
              'warm_start': [False]}

GS_random = RandomizedSearchCV(mlp, param_distributions=param_grid_random,n_jobs= 1,cv=5, scoring='r2', n_iter=100,random_state=42) #scoring='neg_mean_squared_error'
                  
                  
GS_random.fit(X_train, y_train)

print(GS_random.best_params_)
```

{'warm_start': False, 'solver': 'adam', 'max_iter': 10000000000, 'learning_rate': 'constant', 'hidden_layer_sizes': (18, 18, 18), 'early_stopping': False, 'alpha': 0.05, 'activation': 'relu'}

```
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPRegressor
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
mlp = MLPRegressor(random_state=42)
param_grid = {'hidden_layer_sizes': [(17,17,17), (18,18,18), (19,19,19)],
              'activation': ['tanh','relu','logistic'],
              'solver': ['sgd', 'adam'],
              'learning_rate': ['constant','adaptive','invscaling'],
              'alpha': [0.0001, 0.05],
              'max_iter': [10000000000],
              'early_stopping': [False],
              'warm_start': [False]}
GS = GridSearchCV(mlp, param_grid=param_grid,n_jobs= -1,cv=5, scoring='r2') #scoring='neg_mean_squared_error'
                  
                  
GS.fit(X_train, y_train)

print(GS.best_params_)
```

{'activation': 'relu', 'alpha': 0.05, 'early_stopping': False, 'hidden_layer_sizes': (17, 17, 17), 'learning_rate': 'constant', 'max_iter': 10000000000, 'solver': 'adam', 'warm_start': False}

```
mlp_new = MLPRegressor(hidden_layer_sizes=(17, 17,17),
                       max_iter = 10000000000,activation = 'relu',
                       solver = 'adam', learning_rate='constant', 
                       alpha=0.05,validation_fraction=0.2,random_state=0,early_stopping=False)
mlp_new.fit(X_train, y_train)
mlp_new_y_predict = mlp_new.predict((X_test))
mlp_new_y_predict

from sklearn import metrics
MLP_r_square = metrics.r2_score(y_test,mlp_new_y_predict)
print('R-Square for the MLP Regressor is:', MLP_r_square)
```

Comment: How are you producing the R^2 values you've reported?

Comment: @BenReiniger I am using the optimum parameters to create the model then I calculate the coefficient of determination. I've updated my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GridSearchCV` and `RandomizedSearchCV` both take `random_state` parameters. This is different to the random state in the model itself (i.e. `MLPRegressor`) and controls the way in which the data is separated into training and testing datasets.

Try setting the same random state in the different CV calls. It might also be a good idea to pass through a specific [CV splitter](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/glossary.html#term-CV-splitter) (rather than `cv=5`) to ensure reproducibility.

Probably the simplest CV splitter is [KFold](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.KFold.html#sklearn.model_selection.KFold), you can use it with your CV call and a specified random state like this:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
kfold_splitter = KFold(n_splits=5, random_state = 666)

GS_random = RandomizedSearchCV(...,

                               cv=kfold_splitter,

                               ...)
```

The [cross-validation page](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html) in the scikit-learn documentation provides a good description of the different cross-validation iterators. The correct one to use depends on the problem at hand (e.g. do you need to stratify? do you have different groups you need to keep separate?).

Comment: thank you. How can I specify a specific CV splitter in my code?

Comment: and how can I set the same random state in the different CV calls?

Comment: I've edited the answer to include a cv splitter example.

Comment: thank you. I am getting the following error: ValueError: Setting a random_state has no effect since shuffle is False. You should leave random_state to its default (None), or set shuffle=True.

Comment: OK try with `set_shuffle=True` and your random state.

Comment: thank you. `from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
kfold_splitter = KFold(n_splits=5, random_state = 666,shuffle=True)` if I put this it works but is this correct?

Comment: thank you very much you've solved my problem. One last question, do you think I should put: 'early_stopping': [True]? and I can't understand what does this do although I have read about it online but I understand that it can be useful to avoid overfitting?

Comment: Not sure about early stopping, maybe you should ask in a separate question? :)